# one to many relationship in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two classes on Parse.com : Question & Answer. In User class, I am saving 3 fields qid description . In Answer class I have aid,description qid for relation.

I have to create one-to-many relation between these two classes so that I can fetch Answers with the corresponding Questions.

I have created a relation between Question class and Answer class on parse.com with a column named qid in User class. Not able to find how can I fetch the qid with that particular Answer with one-to-many relation.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-one-to-many) in one-to-one and one-to-many relations you should use a **Pointer** and leave Relations to use only on many-to-many relationships.

This documentation will help you with some examples too.

In your situation you will need to save an Answer Pointer inside each Question Class.

Raise some comments if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

From sample curl/Rest access here is a field 'requestedBy' of Type Array, containing pointers to instances of Class User...

To inline the Set of Users who requested, use  " include" in the path parms OR set include on the query...

```
1/classes/Requests?include=requestedBy"

  query.include("requestedBy");
```

sample data-response showing array of pointer that can be included:

```
"requestedBy":[{"__type":"Object","className":"_User","createdAt":"2014-06-18T14:18:39.859Z","name":"rob","objectId":"clChKIvsNw","updatedAt":"2014-06-18T14:18:39.859Z","username":"b"},{"__type":"Object","className":"_User","createdAt":"2014-06-18T14:16:37.529Z","name":"r","objectId":"SHeaXm18Is","updatedAt":"2014-06-18T14:16:37.529Z","username":"re"}]
```